# modulus operator in c++ driving me mad

Tags: c++

my names joe and im running into a few issues with the modulus in c++

heres the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//In short, this is what i am trying to do:
//divide two numbers, and get both the quotient
//and the remainder
//however, as an example, this below produces a remainder
//of 10 
//110 \ 20 should equal 5 remainder 5
int firstInput =110, secondInput = 20;

int quotient = 0, remainder = 0;

quotient = firstInput / secondInput;

remainder = firstInput % secondInput;// i think the problem is here

cout << "The quotient is " << quotient << " and the remainder is "
    << remainder << endl;


system("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

basically its not computing the remainder correctly.
any help of course would be much appreciated. cheers

Comment: "110 \ 20 should equal 5 remainder 5" - this is wrong. 110 mod 20 = 10, so C++ is doing fine here, you're just expecting the wrong answer.

Comment: 5 * 20 + 10 = 110, where's the problem?

Comment: I suppose you messes decimal fraction with divide remainder since 110/20 = 5.5

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not a real question".  Alternately, I could define it as a question about elementary arithmetic and close it as "off topic".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the correct answer...

```
The quotient is 5 and the remainder is 10
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I think the bug is probably located between the keyboard and the chair ... =P

Comment: Haha so true, well at least you put a smile on my face, man I need to brush up on my math I think, or something, cheers :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us. =D

Answer (score 1):

110 = 5*20 + 10

the remainder *is* 10, not 5

Comment: Thanks, i feel kinda embarrassed now, but thanks again otherwise I would have never figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

110 = 5 * 20 + 10, therefore the quotient is 5, and remainder is 10.
So it seems to calculate correctly.

If you want to get the "rest" 0.5, you need to calculate `((double)firstInput/secondInput) - (firstInput/secondInput)`.

Comment: Looks like i was getting rest confused with remainders, thanks for the rest code too, man its been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide 110 by 20, you *should* get a quotient of 5 and a remainder of 10... because:

```
5*20 + 10 = 110
```

Answer (score -1):

try fmod to get what you want.

Comment: From http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/math/fmod
The fmod() function returns the remainder of x/y. 
#include <cmath>
    double fmod( double x, double y );

Better?